# Exporting Form INSERT Queries from Microsoft Access 2007 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I have inherited a MS Access DB (2007) which I am converting into a MySQL database. I have exported all the custom queries with no issues. But I cannot find the form `INSERT` query.

The DB has a form which contains sub-forms. There is one submit button which onclick validates the form and then calls `acCmdSaveRecord` which presumably inserts the record into the database.

Because the database schema is a moderately complex RDB I want to be able to view or export the `INSERT` query Access runs when saving a record so I can convert it to MySQL.

Is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That is done by Access behind the scene when using a bound form.

If you link the table from MySQL and bind your (sub)forms to the updated tables and views, the forms will still read and write your data.